# External polyphase merge sort

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, mergesort

For comparison with other external sorting algorithms, I have implemented *external polyphase merge sort*, purported to be useful to sort large files that do not fit into main memory. More theoretical info about the algorithm itself can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphase_merge_sort).
My implementation uses a *Priority Queue* (PQ) as the internal data structure used to extract the smallest element when needed. Elements of the PQ are of a type `StringRecord` which represents a single line from the main input file.

The algorithm works as expected but it is very slow.
The first - **distribution phase** works just fine without any performance issues.
The problem must be somewhere in the second - **merge phase**. I have already removed/fixed some  minor performance issues but the major issue is obviously still present.
For benchmarking, this [~786 MB input file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W1AZjr5TGpDa0inbDQM_9s_vyPhEUXsT) with 134217728 lines has been generated. In one test with all files on a local WD Blue 1 TB HDD with 16 MB of cache, sorting took about 230 seconds after warm-up. Timing has been established using `System.currentTimeMillis()` & `System.out.println()` as shown.

```
/**
* StringRecord class represent a single line of text in input files that algorithm is working with
* in merge procedure. It is defined by two attributes: value itself and a file index where value is stored in.
*/
public class StringRecord implements Comparable<StringRecord>
{
    /** String value of this StringRecord. */
    private String value;

    /** Index of an input file where this value is stored in. */
    private int file_index;

    /**
    * Constructor used to create new instance of StringRecord class.
    * 
    * @param value      string value of this StringRecord.
    * @param file_index index of a file where @param value is stored in.
    */
    public StringRecord(String value, int file_index)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.file_index = file_index;
    }

    /**
    * Returns value of this StringRecord object.
    */
    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    /**
    * Returns file_index of this StringRecord object.
    */
    public int getFileIndex()
    {
        return file_index;
    }

    /**
    * Compares this StringRecord value to @param string_record value for their lexicographical order.
    *
    * It returns 0 if the argument is a string value lexicographically equal to this string value,
    * less than 0 if the argument is a string value lexicographically greater than
    * this string value and greater than 0 if the argument is a string value lexicographically
    * less than this string value.
    * 
    * @param string_record string record where it's value is compared to this object value.
    */
    public int compareTo(StringRecord string_record)
    {       
        return this.value.compareTo(string_record.value);
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

/**
* PMSS algorithm sorts input text file of strings using polyphase merge procedure with a help of two or more auxilary files.
* In the first part it uses these files to distribute input data and then merges them in the second part.
* <p>
* Distribution of the input data is based on Fibonacci numbers sequence which is depending
* on number of auxilary files that algorithm is working with. The algorithm uses internal
* data structure <i>PriorityQueue</i> to store run elements. Priority queue is also used
* to find a minimum element that will be first written to the output file.
* The algorithm uses a class named <i>StringRecord</i> which represent a single line in
* input file defined by two attributes: value itself and file index where value is stored in.
* All elements of the priority queue are of type StringRecord.
* <p>
* Distribute procedure repeats until entire input data is distributed following Fibonacchi sequence numbers.
* Merge procedure repeats until all the data is sorted in ascending order. The algorithm
* produces a brand new output file which contains sorted data and thus retains input file unchanged.
* <p>
* @param temp_files         number of auxiliary files used for data distribution and merging.
* @param working_dir        path to local directory where all the sorting takes place.
* @param main_string_file   local text file which contains all input data separated by new a line character.
*
* @throws IOException       if an input or output exception occurred during file operations.
*
*/
public class PMSS
{
    /** Amount of input data read by input file reader in distribute phase of the algorithm. */
    static long data_read = 0;

    /** Variable used to store the first element of next run. Used only in writeNextStringRun() method. */
    static String next_run_element;

    /** Index of current active output file where runs are being merged. */
    static int output_file_index;

    /** Index of previous active output file (previous distribution level). */
    static int old_output_file_index;

    /** Amount of runs on current distribution level. */
    static int runs_per_level;

    /** Array used to store missing (dummy) runs for each input file after the distribute phase. */
    static int missing_runs[];

    /** Array used to determine distribution of runs in input files. Each input file should
    * contain exactly the same amount of runs as specified in this arrays indexes.
    **/
    static int distribution_array[];    

    /** Array used as a semaphore for input file readers. If value on a certain index equals 1,
    * input file reader is allowed to read from attached file. If value is 0, reading is not allowed.
    **/
    static int allow_read[];

    /** Array used to store all last elements of the current runs from each input file. */
    static String last_elements[];

    /** Array used to store all last elements of the current runs from each input file. Used only in
    * distribute phase of the algorithm.
    **/
    static String run_last_elements[];

    /** Array used to store all first elements of the next runs from each input file. */
    static StringRecord next_run_first_elements[];

    /** 
    * Main data structure of the algorithm. It is used to extract next minimum string
    * that needs to be written to output file. When q is empty on a certain distribution
    * level, all runs on this level have merged to output file.
    */
    static PriorityQueue<StringRecord> q = new PriorityQueue<StringRecord>();

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        int temp_files = 24;
        String file_extension = ".txt";
        String working_dir = "/path/to/working/directory";
        File main_file = new File(working_dir + "/main" + file_extension);
        File sorted_file = new File(working_dir + "/sorted" + file_extension);
        BufferedReader main_file_reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(main_file));
        long main_file_length = main_file.length();

        File working_files[] = new File[temp_files + 1];

        sorted_file.delete();

        allow_read = new int[temp_files + 1];
        missing_runs = new int[temp_files + 1];
        last_elements = new String[temp_files + 1];
        distribution_array = new int[temp_files + 1];
        run_last_elements = new String[temp_files + 1];
        next_run_first_elements = new StringRecord[temp_files + 1];

        String working_file_name = "working_file_";
        BufferedReader run_file_readers[] = new BufferedReader[temp_files + 1];

        for(int i=0; i<working_files.length; i++)
        {
            working_files[i] = new File(working_dir + working_file_name + (i+1) + file_extension);
        }

        /* START - initial run distribution */

        distribute(temp_files, working_files, main_file_length, main_file_reader);

        /* END - initial run distribution */

        /* START - polyphase merge */

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int min_dummy_values = getMinDummyValue();
        initMergeProcedure(min_dummy_values);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(working_files[output_file_index]));

        for(int i=0; i<run_file_readers.length-1; i++)
        {
            run_file_readers[i] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(working_files[i]));
        }

        while(runs_per_level > 1)
        {
            last_elements[output_file_index] = null;
            merge(distribution_array[getMinFileIndex()] - min_dummy_values, run_file_readers, writer);

            setPreviousRunDistributionLevel();
            updateOutputFileIndex();
            resetAllowReadArray();

            min_dummy_values = getMinDummyValue();
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(working_files[output_file_index]));
            run_file_readers[old_output_file_index] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(working_files[old_output_file_index]));
        }

        writer.close();
        main_file_reader.close();
        closeReaders(run_file_readers);
        clearTempFiles(working_dir, main_file, working_files);

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        /* END - polyphase merge */

        System.out.println("Merge phase done in " + (end-start) + " ms");
    }

    /**
    * Distributes contents of main input file to @temp_files temporary output files.
    * Input data is distributed according to distribution_array which contains for
    * every temporary file a predifined amount of runs that should reside in certain file
    * on a certain distribution level. Calculation of array values is based on Fibonacci
    * sequence numbers. When input data on a certain level is distributed, next level is calculated
    * if and only if the input file is not consumed yet.
    * 
    * @param temp_files       number of temporary files to work with.
    * @param working_files    array of all working files. The size of this array equals @temp_files.
    * @param main_file_length length of the main input file.
    * @param main_file_reader reader used to read main input file.
    */
    private static void distribute(int temp_files, File working_files[], long main_file_length, BufferedReader main_file_reader)
    {
        try
        {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            runs_per_level = 1;
            distribution_array[0] = 1;
            output_file_index = working_files.length - 1;

            int write_sentinel[] = new int[temp_files];
            BufferedWriter run_file_writers[] = new BufferedWriter[temp_files];

            for(int i=0; i<temp_files; i++)
            {
                run_file_writers[i] = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(working_files[i],true));
            }

            /* START - distribute runs */
            while(data_read < main_file_length)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<temp_files; i++)
                {
                    while(write_sentinel[i] != distribution_array[i])
                    {
                        while(runsMerged(main_file_length, i, next_run_element))
                        {
                            writeNextStringRun(main_file_length, main_file_reader, run_file_writers[i], i);
                        }

                        writeNextStringRun(main_file_length, main_file_reader, run_file_writers[i], i);
                        missing_runs[i]++;
                        write_sentinel[i]++;
                    }
                }
                setNextDistributionLevel();
            }

            closeWriters(run_file_writers);

            setPreviousRunDistributionLevel();
            setMissingRunsArray();

            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Distribute phase done in " + (end-start) + " ms");

            /* END - distribute runs */
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown in distribute(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
    * Merges predefined amount of dummy runs from all input files to output file.
    * Amount of dummy runs that can be merged is defined by @param min_dummy.
    * Since there should be no special markers in input files, all the merging results
    * as adequate substraction/addition in missing_runs array.
    * Additionaly this method resets allow_read array once dummy run merge is over.
    *
    * @param min_dummy minimum amount of runs which is the same for all input files.
    */
    private static void initMergeProcedure(int min_dummy)
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=0; i<missing_runs.length - 1; i++)
            {
                missing_runs[i] -= min_dummy;
            }

            missing_runs[output_file_index] += min_dummy;

            resetAllowReadArray();
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown in initMergeProcedure(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
    * Merges @param min_file_values runs into a single run and writes it to output file bounded by @param writer.
    * @param min_file_values is a minimum number of runs per current distribution level. Procedure merges @param min_file_values
    * from all of the input files and terminates afterwards.
    *
    * @param min_file_values  number of runs that will be merged in a single execution of merge procedure.
    * @param run_file_readers array of all input file readers.
    * @param writer           writer for output file.
    */
    private static void merge(int min_file_values, BufferedReader run_file_readers[], BufferedWriter writer)
    {
        String line;
        int min_file;
        int heap_empty = 0;
        StringRecord record;

        /* Initial heap population */
        populateHeap(run_file_readers);

        try
        {
            while(heap_empty != min_file_values)
            {
                record = q.poll();
                writer.write(record.getValue() + "\n");
                min_file = record.getFileIndex();

                if(allow_read[min_file] == 1 && (line = readFileLine(run_file_readers[min_file],min_file)) != null)
                {
                    q.add(new StringRecord(line,min_file));
                }

                try
                {
                    /* Once heap is empty all n-th runs have merged */
                    if(q.size() == 0)
                    {
                        heap_empty++;

                        for(int i=0; i<next_run_first_elements.length; i++)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                q.add(new StringRecord(next_run_first_elements[i].getValue(),i));
                                last_elements[i] = next_run_first_elements[i].getValue();
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){}
                        }

                        populateHeap(run_file_readers);
                        resetAllowReadArray();

                        if(heap_empty == min_file_values)
                        {
                            writer.close();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){}
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown in merge(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
    * Updates current output_file_index which points to output file where runs are being merged to.
    */
    private static void updateOutputFileIndex()
    {
        if(output_file_index > 0)
        {
            output_file_index--;
        }
        else
        {
            output_file_index = distribution_array.length - 1;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Reads next value of each run into a priority queue. Reading is allowed if certain input file
    * contains no dummy runs and reading from input file is allowed by allow_read array.
    *
    * @param run_file_readers array of all input file readers.
    */
    private static void populateHeap(BufferedReader run_file_readers[])
    {
        try
        {
            String line;

            for(int i=0;i<run_file_readers.length;i++)
            {
                if(missing_runs[i] == 0)
                {
                    if((allow_read[i] == 1) && (line = readFileLine(run_file_readers[i],i)) != null)
                    {
                        q.add(new StringRecord(line,i));
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    missing_runs[i]--;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception thrown while initial heap population: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
    * Reads next line of text from file bounded by @param file_reader.
    * 
    * @param file_reader reader used to read from input file.
    * @param file_index  index of a file from which @param file_reader reads the data.
    * @return next line of text from file, null instead.
    */
    private static String readFileLine(BufferedReader file_reader, int file_index)
    {
        try
        {
            String current_line = file_reader.readLine();

            /* End of run */
            if(last_elements[file_index] != null && current_line.compareTo(last_elements[file_index]) < 0)
            {               
                next_run_first_elements[file_index] = new StringRecord(current_line,file_index);
                allow_read[file_index] = 0;

                return null;
            }

            else
            {
                last_elements[file_index] = current_line;
                return current_line;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            allow_read[file_index] = 0;
            next_run_first_elements[file_index] = null;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
    * Resets allow_read array to its initial state. It additionally sets
    * index of output_file_index to 0 and thus prevents read operations
    * from output file.
    */
    private static void resetAllowReadArray()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<allow_read.length; i++)
        {
            allow_read[i] = 1;
        }

        allow_read[output_file_index] = 0;
    }

    /**
    * Returns the minimum amount of dummy runs present amongst input files.
    *
    * @return the minimum amount of present runs.
    */
    private static int getMinDummyValue()
    {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for(int i=0; i<missing_runs.length; i++)
        {
            if(i != output_file_index && missing_runs[i] < min)
            {
                min = missing_runs[i];
            }
        }

        return min;
    }

    /**
    * Returns index of a file which according to distribution_array contains the minimum amount of runs.
    *
    * @return index of a file with minimum amount of runs.
    */
    private static int getMinFileIndex()
    {
        int min_file_index = -1;
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        for(int i=0; i<distribution_array.length; i++)
        {
            if(distribution_array[i] != 0 && distribution_array[i] < min)
            {
                min_file_index = i;
            }
        }

        return min_file_index;
    }

    /**
    * Writes next string run to output file pointed by @param run_file_writer.
    * 
    * @param main_file_length length of the main input file.
    * @param main_file_reader reader used to read main input file.
    * @param run_file_writer  writer used to write to a specific output file
    * @param file_index       used to update missing_runs and run_last_elements arrays.
    *                         In case when main input file is read to the end amount of
    *                         dummy runs on this index in missing_runs array needs to be
    *                         decreased. When run is ended run_last_elements array on
    *                         this index is populated with the last element of the run.
    *                         
    */
    private static void writeNextStringRun(long main_file_length, BufferedReader main_file_reader, BufferedWriter run_file_writer, int file_index)
    {
        if(data_read >= main_file_length)
        {
            missing_runs[file_index]--;
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            if(next_run_element != null)
            {
                run_file_writer.write(next_run_element + "\n");             
                data_read += next_run_element.length() + 1;
            }

            String min_value = "";
            String current_line = main_file_reader.readLine();          

            /* Case if run is a single element: acordingly update variables and return */
            if(next_run_element != null)
            {               
                if(next_run_element.compareTo(current_line) > 0)
                {
                    run_last_elements[file_index] = next_run_element;
                    next_run_element = current_line;

                    return;
                }
            }

            while(current_line !=  null)
            {               
                if(current_line.compareTo(min_value) >= 0)
                {
                    run_file_writer.write(current_line + "\n");                 
                    data_read += current_line.length() + 1;

                    min_value = current_line;
                    current_line = main_file_reader.readLine();                 
                }

                else
                {
                    next_run_element = current_line;
                    run_last_elements[file_index] = min_value;

                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }

    /**
    * Checks if two adjacent runs have merged into a single run. It does this by comparing the first element
    * of the second run with the last element of the first run. If this two elements are in sorted order, the runs
    * have merged.
    * 
    * @param main_file_length length of the main input file.
    * @param file_index       index in array from which last element of the first run is taken for comparison.
    * @param first_element    first element of the second run to be taken into comparison.
    * @return true if the runs have merged, false instead.
    */
    private static boolean runsMerged(long main_file_length, int file_index, String first_element)
    {
        if(data_read < main_file_length && run_last_elements[file_index] != null && first_element != null)
        {           
            return run_last_elements[file_index].compareTo(first_element) <= 0 ? true:false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
    * Calculates next run distribution level. The new level is calculated following
    * Finonacchi sequence rule.
    */
    private static void setNextDistributionLevel()
    {
        runs_per_level = 0;
        int current_distribution_array[] = distribution_array.clone();

        for(int i=0; i<current_distribution_array.length - 1; i++)
        {
            distribution_array[i] = current_distribution_array[0] + current_distribution_array[i+1];
            runs_per_level +=  distribution_array[i];
        }
    }

    /**
    * Calculates previous run distribution level. The new level is calculated following.
    * Finonacchi sequence rule.
    */
    private static void setPreviousRunDistributionLevel()
    {
        int diff;
        int current_distribution_array[] = distribution_array.clone();
        int last = current_distribution_array[current_distribution_array.length - 2];

        old_output_file_index = output_file_index;

        runs_per_level = 0;
        runs_per_level += last;
        distribution_array[0] = last;

        for(int i=current_distribution_array.length - 3; i>=0; i--)
        {
            diff = current_distribution_array[i] - last;
            distribution_array[i+1] = diff;
            runs_per_level += diff;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Calculates the amount of dummy runs for every input file after distribute phase of the algorithm.
    */
    private static void setMissingRunsArray()
    {   
        for(int i=0; i<distribution_array.length - 1; i++)
        {
            missing_runs[i] = (distribution_array[i] - missing_runs[i]);
        }
    }

    /**
    * Closes all file readers used to read from run files in distribute phase of the algorithm.
    * 
    * @param run_file_readers array of readers to read from run files.
    */
    private static void closeReaders(BufferedReader run_file_readers[])
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=0; i<run_file_readers.length; i++)
            {
                run_file_readers[i].close();
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e){}
    }

    /**
    * Closes all file writers used to write to run files in distribute phase of the algorithm.
    * 
    * @param run_file_writers array of writers to write to run files.
    */
    private static void closeWriters(BufferedWriter run_file_writers[])
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i=0; i<run_file_writers.length; i++)
            {
                run_file_writers[i].close();
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e){}
    }

    /**
    * Clears all unnecessary temporary files and renames the sorted one to its final name.
    * 
    * @param working_dir path to working directory where entire sorting process is taking place.
    * @param main_file main input file.
    * @param temp_files number of temporary files to work with.
    */
    private static void clearTempFiles(String working_dir, File main_file, File temp_files[])
    {
        File sorted_file = new File(working_dir+"sorted.txt");

        for(int i=0; i<temp_files.length; i++)
        {
            if(temp_files[i].length() == main_file.length())
            {
                temp_files[i].renameTo(sorted_file);
                temp_files[i].delete();
            }

            temp_files[i].delete();
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: (Welcome to CodeReview!) That is a lot of code: does it contain everything to reproduce the timing issues? Can you give an overview of the strategy used? (Beyond *algorithm*: are the files in tmp files on disks, SSD, cloud? Synchronous IO or not? (you import io, not nio?!) …) What *are* your findings about where wall clock time goes: key comparison? Waiting for file input? Output? Copying records from buffer to buffer? (For laughs: PQ operations?) How did you establish temporal performance? What can you say about the input: number of records and distribution of key length & record size?

Comment: (Can't remember seeing source on CR before that made me think *running javadoc is bound to provide me with food for thought if not insight*: well done!)

Comment: @greybeard this is all the code I have. What do you mean by "strategy used"? All the temporary files that algorithm works with are stored on a local WD Blue 1 TB HDD with 16 MB of cache. The main input file for the algorithm is .txt file with strings of a random lengths (1-15) separated by a new line character. All the files that algorithm works with (temp files, main input file, final sorted file) are stored in the same directory defined by working_dir variable. There is no special order defined for the main file - it is randomly distributed.

Comment: I don't have useful idea why it works so slow. Key (string) comparison is by default slow since comparing strings right? One idea is that writing is somehow slow (despite I am using BufferedWritter and BufferedReader). There is no special wait for input/output file(s), it is just the sort phase that needs to finish. Just an example of timing: sorting txt file with 134217728 lines (786 MB) takes about 260 second. If running the algorithm in loop for about 10 times, this time stabilises at around 230 seconds. I can link the file if needed?

Comment: `main input […] is .txt file with strings of a random lengths (1-15) …` This looks *generated file*: rather than linking to such a file, include the generator source. *Strategy*: I gave two examples of *what* hoping for *why*s, more: how many files to use (symmetric merge can be expected to use *less* passes above 8), "character set" or unicode I/O. *How* did you establish `distribution phase works just fine without any performance issues` and `merge phase […] major issue […] still present`?

Comment: (Just started tinkering - timing seems to be much worse (~50 seconds for distribution)?! From the temp file sizes, something is very, very wrong. (Like my picture of the workings of polyphase merge, maybe.) hm. Keeping one core semi-busy.)

Comment: I find repeated strings in the output that are not repeated in the input - dummy run handling seems to be off.

Comment: I am sorry but the generator used to generate this file is gone, that is why I posted link to it. The input file was generated picking random strings from https://norvig.com/big.txt.

Comment: I was apparently wrong about distribute phase performance. In comparison with merge phase it is much faster. But still: since I have to check if every two adjacent runs have merged that must add something to timing issue?

Comment: Your main problem here is that, contrary to your claim, your distribution phase does not work ***at all.*** It doesn't even produce runs of 2. So you are spending 99.9% of your time merging. You should use a PQ size of 256 or 1024 or even 4096 rather than the very niggardly size of 24 in the distribution phase. However there are many other problems here: NPEs acting as loop breakers. Conversely, you should also be aware that polyphase is barely more efficient with 8 files rather than 6 (Knuth vol 3), and going up 24 yields little or no benefit over 8

Answer (score 2):

> The algorithm works as expected …

How do you know? Sketch what tests you did how.

> …but it is very slow.

My current take: due to Exception handling, due in turn to ***not*** working as specified.
(Test input: download of [norvig.com/big.txt](https://norvig.com/big.txt) - loads of `NullPointerException` trying to dereference `next_run_first_elements[i]`.)

---

For every class where instances can be expected to turn up in arrays, collections and such, override `toString()`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringBuilder().append(value)
        .append('#').append(file_index).toString();
}
```

I failed to come up with a *good* summary of what `setNextDistributionLevel()` and `setPreviousRunDistributionLevel()` do, which is why I present the 1st *without doc comment*. (The naming is inconsistent.)

```
private static void setNextDistributionLevel()
{
    final int
        ways_1 = distribution_array.length - 2,
        diff = distribution_array[0];
    for (int i = 0, next ; i <= ways_1 ; i = next)
        distribution_array[i] = distribution_array[next = i+1] + diff;
    runs_per_level += diff * ways_1;
    // System.out.println("next " + runs_per_level + ": " + Arrays.toString(distribution_array));
}

/**
* Calculates previous run distribution level:
* every number of runs is smaller than in the previous level
*  by the smallest number therein */// ToDo: describe commendably
private static void setPreviousRunDistributionLevel()
{
    final int 
        ways_1 = distribution_array.length - 2,
        diff = distribution_array[ways_1];

    for (int i = ways_1, next ; 0 < i ; i = next)
        distribution_array[i] = distribution_array[next = i-1] - diff;
    runs_per_level -= diff * ways_1;
    distribution_array[0] = diff;
    // System.out.println("prev " + runs_per_level + ": " + Arrays.toString(distribution_array));
}
```

`closeReaders()` & `closeWriters()` contain repeated code and don't live up to their documentation in case of an exception - suggestion:

```
/** Closes all Writers in <code>run_file_writers</code>. */
private static void closeWriters(BufferedWriter run_file_writers[]) {
    closeAll(run_file_writers);
}

/** Closes all <code>candidates</code>. */
private static void closeAll(Closeable candidates[]) {
    for (Closeable candidate: candidates)
        try {
            candidate.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
}
```

Use the runtime environmnt's support in favour of open coding, e.g. `Arrays.fill()` instead of iterating over array indices to assign to elements.

Comment: (Musing doing a full code review once the question supports reproduction of timing issues.)

Comment: ***Guesses*** about causes for unsatisfactory speed: **1)  Not creating initial runs of max. achievable size** (1st sentence of en.wikipedia's article…) **2)** Choice of algorithm. *Polyphase merge* looked a Good Idea when when your computing centre had nine tape drives (four fast, two of the sluggish not able to read backwards, two of the fast ones able to *write* backwards (and two dead ones for spares) - and at any given time, seven could be expected in working condition, but at most five available for data tapes of any single job of a mere mortal).

Comment: Regarding 1): I am not sure if I understand what seems to be a problem with initial runs and their max. achievable size? I just distribute the runs following distribution array. Regarding 2): since I am comparing this algorithm with other external sorting algorithms, the choice is not really a question. I have applied your suggestion with closeables, will also change IO for NIO. Have you noticed any other issues in the code? Thanks.

Comment: **3)** using too few files **4)** using buffers no larger than the smallish default size. *(More) Things that justifying experimentation*: **a)** using unicode in temp files instead of en-/decoding time&again **b)** asynchronous I/O

Comment: `I just distribute the runs` detected in the input - which would be the thing to do in the *internal sort* algorithm *natural merge*. For an external merge, use the biggest PQ you can justify to create *initial runs* with an expected length about twice the capacity of that PQ, and proportionally fewer of those. (Say 1GB for a PQ of 9 char Strings - I'd expect runs of about 50E6 records, as opposed to 1.5 for "natural" - a factor of about 30E6. With an approximate reduction factor of 4.3 for a 20 file polyphase merge, that's almost 12 passes saved.)

Comment: I have measured the execution time with System.currentTimeMillis() & System.out.println(), no other code used. I will post the link from where you can download the input file or will try to find the generator. The files were generated some time ago.

Comment: As promised here is the link to input file (cca 786MB txt file with random string distribution): https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W1AZjr5TGpDa0inbDQM_9s_vyPhEUXsT Change the working directory path and run the algorithm with 24 working files (on Linux or macOS). If you need any more info please let me know.

Comment: Regarding 3) and 4): 24 temporary files is a max I use in my comparison and default buffer size is used for all other algorithms. And by the way I do not use NIO with other algorithms.

Comment: (@henrich If a prospective follow-up is about performance, too, please invest more diligence in establishing a base line such that reviewers can decide for themselves they have reproduced the issue(s) and are in a position to improve the implementation. Such as *issue: merge unexpectedly slow compared to distribute* - provide timings for both!)